# If I remote connect to someone else's computer with their knowledge via RDP, is it possible for them to steal my windows password?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, vpn, remote-desktop

The title says it all. If I connect to someone else's computer with their knowledge remotely via RDP, is it possible for them to steal my windows password? Both party using Windows 10. We are both in the same network due to VPN usage.

Comment: Are your computers both in an Active Directory environment? Does your question imply "without me explicitly entering that password"? What skill level do you expect from your colleague – i.e. would they be capable of using Linux, setting up a malicious RDP server?

Comment: remote one is in Active directory. Client (me) connects to VPN with the help of Pulse Secure and then be able to establish a connection to remote. I don't enter my password anywhere on remote. He's been known very knowledgeable so my answer is yes.